# docker-compose build php-fpm - E: Unable to locate package lib - failed to solve: executor failed running - exit code: 100

Tags: docker, laradock

I have read several posts but I do not understand what to do to solve the problem... so I need your help.

My Apple MacBook Pro laptop was stolen.  Fortunately I had a complete backup. I am using Laravel, Laradock & Docker Desktop.  When I launched Docker Desktop, there was no container Laradock.

So I went on Terminal and starting re-building...

```
cd Sites/laradock
docker-compose build apache2
docker-compose build mailhog
docker-compose build php-fpm
```

The first 2 build ok, but php-fpm gives an error.

```
 laradock % docker-compose build php-fpm                                         
 [+] Building 4.9s (8/85)                                                                                                                            
  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                           0.0s
  => => transferring dockerfile: 274B                                                                                                           0.0s
  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                              0.0s
  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                0.0s
  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/laradock/php-fpm:latest-8.2                                                                         2.8s
  => [internal] load build context                                                                                                              0.0s
  => => transferring context: 132B                                                                                                              0.0s
  => [ 1/81] FROM docker.io/laradock/php-fpm:latest-8.2@sha256:ab3084afd95dabca7aebf83c24d46f2859ca3c8b6a93de826365354a6369630a                 0.0s
  => CACHED [ 2/81] RUN if [ false = true ]; then     sed -i 's/deb.debian.org/mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/' /etc/apt/sources.list &&     sed  0.0s
  => CACHED [ 3/81] RUN set -xe;     apt-get update -yqq &&     pecl channel-update pecl.php.net &&     apt-get install -yqq       apt-utils    0.0s
  => ERROR [ 4/81] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpa  2.0s
 ------                                                                                                                                              
  > [ 4/81] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 lib lib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils wget:
 #0 0.953 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
 #0 1.073 Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
 #0 1.218 Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
 #0 1.268 Reading package lists...
 #0 1.586 Reading package lists...
 #0 1.868 Building dependency tree...
 #0 1.930 Reading state information...
 #0 1.960 E: Unable to locate package lib
 ------
 failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 lib lib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils wget]: exit code: 100
```

I ran that command a few months ago on my previous laptop with no problem.

Here is the content of docker-compose.yml for php/fpm...

```
php-fpm:
  build:
    context: ./php-fpm
    args:
      - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
      - BASE_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX=${PHP_FPM_BASE_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX}
      - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
      - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
      - INSTALL_BZ2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BZ2}
      - INSTALL_ENCHANT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ENCHANT}
      - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GMP}
      - INSTALL_GNUPG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GNUPG}
      - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
      - XDEBUG_PORT=${PHP_FPM_XDEBUG_PORT}
      - INSTALL_PCOV=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PCOV}
      - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
      - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
      - INSTALL_SSH2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSH2}
      - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
      - INSTALL_XSL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XSL}
      - INSTALL_SMB=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SMB}
      - INSTALL_IMAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAP}
      - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
      - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AMQP}
      - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
      - INSTALL_ZMQ=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZMQ}
      - INSTALL_GEARMAN=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GEARMAN}
      - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
      - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
      - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
      - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
      - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
      - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
      - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
      - INSTALL_OCI8=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OCI8}
      - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
      - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL}
      - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
      - PG_CLIENT_VERSION=${POSTGRES_CLIENT_VERSION}
      - INSTALL_POSTGIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_POSTGIS}
      - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
      - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
      - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
      - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHALCON}
      - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
      - INSTALL_TAINT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TAINT}
      - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
      - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
      - INSTALL_CALENDAR=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CALENDAR}
      - INSTALL_XLSWRITER=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XLSWRITER}
      - INSTALL_FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_FAKETIME}
      - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
      - INSTALL_APCU=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_APCU}
      - INSTALL_CACHETOOL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CACHETOOL}
      - INSTALL_YAML=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_YAML}
      - INSTALL_RDKAFKA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_RDKAFKA}
      - INSTALL_GETTEXT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GETTEXT}
      - INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES}
      - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
      - INSTALL_PING=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PING}
      - INSTALL_SSHPASS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSHPASS}
      - INSTALL_MAILPARSE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MAILPARSE}
      - INSTALL_PCNTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PCNTL}
      - ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=${PHP_FPM_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES}
      - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${PHP_FPM_FFMPEG}
      - INSTALL_AUDIOWAVEFORM=${PHP_FPM_AUDIOWAVEFORM}
      - INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF}
      - WKHTMLTOPDF_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_WKHTMLTOPDF_VERSION}
      - INSTALL_XHPROF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XHPROF}
      - INSTALL_XMLRPC=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XMLRPC}
      - INSTALL_PHPDECIMAL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDECIMAL}
      - INSTALL_ZOOKEEPER=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZOOKEEPER}
      - INSTALL_SSDB=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSDB}
      - INSTALL_TRADER=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TRADER}
      - INSTALL_EVENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EVENT}
      - DOWNGRADE_OPENSSL_TLS_AND_SECLEVEL=${PHP_DOWNGRADE_OPENSSL_TLS_AND_SECLEVEL}
      - DOWNGRADE_OPENSSL_TLS_VERSION=${PHP_DOWNGRADE_OPENSSL_TLS_VERSION}
      - PUID=${PHP_FPM_PUID}
      - PGID=${PHP_FPM_PGID}
      - IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION=${PHP_FPM_IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}
      - LOCALE=${PHP_FPM_DEFAULT_LOCALE}
      - PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC=${PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC}
      - PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_KEY=${PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_KEY}
      - PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME=${PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}
      - INSTALL_DOCKER_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_DOCKER_CLIENT}
      - INSTALL_DNSUTILS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_DNSUTILS}
      - http_proxy
      - https_proxy
      - no_proxy
  volumes:
    - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
    - docker-in-docker:/certs/client
  expose:
    - "9000"
  extra_hosts:
    - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
  environment:
    - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
    - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2376
    - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
    - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
    - FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_FAKETIME}
  depends_on:
    - workspace
  networks:
    - backend
  links:
    - docker-in-docker
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Don't focus on docker-compose.yml, but focus on your Dockerfile. In instruction #4, it returns an error: `Unable to locate package lib`. If you want, you can cut up that instruction to figure out which package is missing. You can also comment out that instruction and add it after the image has built. It's kind of debugging but then with a Dockerfile instead of something like PHP

Comment: The message is saying there isn't a [package](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) named `lib`.  The following `lib2.0-0` in the error message also looks suspicious.  You'd need to fix the package list in your Dockerfile.  If the list is supposed to be alphabetical, do you mean [`libglib2.0-0`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libglib2.0-0) here?

Comment: @UnderDog Sorry guys... which one is my docker file? docker-sync.yml?

Comment: @DavidMaze What I do not understand is why is this docker file not working now and working 6 months ago?

Comment: @UnderDog There is a Dockerfile in almost each folder in Laradock... so which one should I look at?

Comment: @UnderDog There is a Dockerfile in php-fpm... I guess that is the one and I see that the reference to lib2.0-0 is part of Browsershot/ Puppeteer which I never managed to get to work... so I removed these lines and it seems to work... Thank you!